# Refresh webpage on change in folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web, flask

**I want to refresh my web page every time a file is uploaded to the folder.**

I have a web service written in flask having the following handler

```
@app.route('/getlatest/')
def getlatest():
    import os
    import glob
    newset = max(glob.iglob('static/*'),key=os.path.getctime)
    Return newest;
```

This gives me the name of the latest file in the folder.

I have an Ajax call in my JS (client side) to constantly get data from above function.

```
function GetLatest()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/getlatest", 
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        if(previousName != result){
                            previousName = result;
                            $("#image").attr("src","/"+previousName);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

function calling server every second.

```
(function myLoop (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
    GetLatest();                         
    if (--i) myLoop(i);
       }, 1000)
})(100);
```

This Works fine [well almost].
***My Question is: Is there any better way to do it[ there must be ]?***

i'm open to technology choices what every they may be [node, angualr etc.]

Comment: What you are looking for is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: does the file upload code reside in the same page? if so you can handle the refresh on the success of your file upload post call

Comment: @JefreeSujit No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how i did it.

first of all thanks to 
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent
for explaining it perfectly.

What i have learnt reading a couple of blogs.

All communication initiated using http protocol is client server communication, and client is always the initiator. So in this case we have to use a different protocol: Web-sockets which allow you to create a full-duplex (two way) connection.

Here is the server code;

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)
thread = None
prevFileName = ""

def background_thread():
    prevFileName = ""
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(0.5)
        if(isNewImageFileAdded(prevFileName) == "true"):
            prevFileName = getLatestFileName()
            socketio.emit('my_response',
              {'data': prevFileName, 'count': 0},
              namespace='/test');

def getLatestFileName():
    return max(glob.iglob('static/*'),key=os.path.getctime)

def isNewImageFileAdded(prevFileName):
    latestFileName = max(glob.iglob('static/*'),key=os.path.getctime)
    if(prevFileName == latestFileName):
        return "false"
    else:
        return "true"
```

Creating separate thread to keep the socket open. *emit* sends the msg to the client from server...

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)
    emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})
```

And here is Client Side.[replaced ajax call with the following code]

```
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + 
location.port + namespace);

socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {    
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#image").attr("src","/"+msg.data)},1000)
                });
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

yea you can use websockets(flask-socketio).That will let you to have an open connection between you and server and every time in the folder is a new photo will be displayed  on a selected div

```
http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-SocketIO/2.9.1
```